# Unhandled Microsoft .NET Framework Exception exception 

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

Recently there was some upgrade happened from frame work 2.0 to 4.0, so after building the project when we click the application it is throwing error? what does it mean "`Unhandled Microsoft .NET Framework Exception exception occurred in tander.exe[400]`" ? **What does [400] means** ? Does it related to any signing issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This usually just means that you need to end the webserver process(es) and try again. Every now and then the Visual Studio Web Server needs a poke in my experience.

Comment: does that represent event ID?